# Fail to open file in C# after editing it in another process

Tags: c#, perl, ipc

I'm using a helper class for running external process:

```
class ExternalProcessRunner
{
    static public string Run(string program, string parameters)
    {
        output = "";
        error = "";
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = program;
            startInfo.Arguments = parameters;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            StringBuilder outputSB = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder errorSB = new StringBuilder();

            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            using (AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
            using (AutoResetEvent errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
            {
                exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        outputWaitHandle.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outputSB.AppendLine(e.Data);
                    }
                };
                exeProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        errorWaitHandle.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorSB.AppendLine(e.Data);
                    }
                };

                exeProcess.Start();

                exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                exeProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                outputWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                errorWaitHandle.WaitOne();

                output = outputSB.ToString();
                error = errorSB.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }

        return "";
    }

    static public string output;
    static public string error;
}
```

It is used to run a perl script which accepts a filename, opens a file, writes some information and closes a file. Then C# code opens that file for reading. Sometimes I get an exception:
"The process cannot access the file 'tmp_file.txt' because it is being used by another process."
What can cause the problem? How to fix it? I think that I'm ensuring the ending of process which means freeing all handles.

Comment: May be the script does not exit properly(Sometimes) so that file is sill opened from there..

Comment: Knowing what process(es) that have the file open would be a good first step. On Windows SysInternal's Process Explorer and Handles tools will get you this information.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have exited the process i.e. you released the file from the memory.

Comment: I do WaitForExit, and Process object disposes due to "using".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a set number of seconds to wait for the process to exit. Then check if it has exited. If it hasn't, then try and kill the process.

In the example below, it waits for 1 minute for the process to exit. If it doesn't exit, then it sensd a command to close the main window and sleep for 2 seconds. If it still hasn't exited then it tries to kill the process.
At the stage the external process should be gone and the lock released on the file.

```
 exeProcess.WaitForExit(1 * 60 * 1000);

if (!exeProcess.HasExited)
{
    _log.Warn("External process has not completed after {0} minutes - trying to close main window", waitTimeMin);
    exeProcess.CloseMainWindow();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

if (!exeProcess.HasExited)
{
    _log.Warn("External process still has not completed - Killing process and waiting for it to exit...");
    exeProcess.Kill();
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to kill it. I want to wait till process actually exits.